# DSolve not solving my system of ODEs

Tags: differential-equations

Does anyone know why `DSolve` does not work for this set of differential equations?

```
DSolve[{
  ca1'[t] == -K1 ca1[t] cb1[t] + K2 cab1[t],
  cb1'[t] == -K1 ca1[t] cb1[t] + K2 cab1[t] - K3 cb1[t] cc1[t] + K4 cbc1[t],
  cab1'[t] == K1 ca1[t] cb1[t] - K2 cab1[t],
  cc1'[t] == -K3 cb1[t] cc1[t] + K4 cbc1[t],
  cbc1'[t] == K3 cb1[t] cc1[t] - K4 cbc1[t],
  ca1[0] == 100, cb1[0] == 100, cab1[0] == 0, cc1[0] == 100, cbc1[0] == 0}, 
  {ca1, cb1, cab1, cc1, cbc1}, t]
```

The output is just a reiteration of the above input.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too localized; i.e, it applies only to the local situation and needs of its poster and answers will not benefit others.

Comment: I learned from it, as an example for a Mathematica newbie.    I could have learned more, maybe.

Comment: {cab1, cbc1, cab1} can be eliminated symbolically from the equations, leaving a second-order system.  The system can be further reduced, if `K1/K2 == K3/K4`.

Answer (score 2):

It may be that there is no closed form solution. However, with the constants assigned numerical values, NDSolve can find a numerical solution:

```
constants = {K1 -> 1, K2 -> 1, K3 -> 1, K4 -> 1};

sol = NDSolveValue[{ca1'[t] == -K1 ca1[t] cb1[t] + K2 cab1[t], 
     cb1'[t] == -K1 ca1[t] cb1[t] + K2 cab1[t] - K3 cb1[t] cc1[t] + 
       K4 cbc1[t], cab1'[t] == K1 ca1[t] cb1[t] - K2 cab1[t], 
     cc1'[t] == -K3 cb1[t] cc1[t] + K4 cbc1[t], 
     cbc1'[t] == K3 cb1[t] cc1[t] - K4 cbc1[t], ca1[0] == 100, 
     cb1[0] == 100, cab1[0] == 0, cc1[0] == 100, cbc1[0] == 0} /. 
    constants, {ca1[t], cb1[t], cab1[t], cc1[t], cbc1[t]}, {t, 0, .1}];


Plot[sol // Evaluate, {t, 0, .1}, 
 PlotLegends -> {ca1[t], cb1[t], cab1[t], cc1[t], cbc1[t]}]
```

[image]